# How to add an Indicator to UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller, uiactivityindicatorview

I have an image picker to pick multiple images from the photo library. The picked photos are resized and saved to file in `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:`. It takes a few seconds.

Could I put an indicator on the view?
I have tried to use `addSubview:indicatorView` in `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` method. But *indicatorView* doesn't appear. It gets dismissed with the imagePickerView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the UIActivityIndicatorView at the top of the view hierarchy or it will get dismissed with the UIPickerViewController, unless you use a callback after the resize operation and in the callback you dismiss the UIImagePickerController.

Or you could use a progress HUD like [SVProgressHUD](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD).

Hope this helps =)

We did a little chat session and solved this way:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{ 
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
          UIView *primaryImage = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,460)]; 
          primaryImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; 
          primaryImage.alpha =0.9; 

          UIView *secondaryImage = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,70,70)]; 
          secondaryImage.center = CGPointMake(160, 240); 
          secondaryImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor]; 
          secondaryImage.alpha = 0.9; 
          secondaryImage.layer.cornerRadius = 12; 
          [primaryImage addSubview:secondaryImage]; 
          UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 25)]; 
          indicator.center = CGPointMake(35, 35); 
          [indicator setHidesWhenStopped:NO]; 
          [secondaryImage addSubview:indicator]; 
          [indicator startAnimating]; 

          [indicator release]; 
          [secondaryImage release]; 

          [picker.view addSubview:primaryImage]; 

         [primaryImage release]; 
     }); 

    // Put here the code to resize the image 

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
    // Dismiss the picker controller

    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, i put it at the top of the view hierarchy, but it did not show up, until the dismissing animated period. That's what i mean "it will get dismissed with the UIPickerViewController".

Comment: For "at the top of the view hierarchy" I mean in the UIWindow. Anyway you could try to add the UIIndicatorView when you create the UIPickerController and control it with a ivar.

Comment: You mean add to the Window? let me try, still do not work. Yes I have created an indicator and hide it first, but once i set the hidden to NO, it doesn't work.

Comment: Is indicator an UIActivityIndicatorView instance? If yes, you should use hidesWhenStopped and then it will be visible when you call the startAnimating method.

Comment: Actually I put the indicatorView in side anotherUIView. such as  [anotherUIView addSubview:indicator]; And try to control the anotherUIView to hide and show.

Comment: I employed the ELCImagePickerController. Just modify the code inside "- (void)elcImagePickerController:(ELCImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSArray *)info " method. There i will resize and save the picked photos, so it takes a few seconds. https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11199/discussion-between-greyhands-and-lu-yuan)

Comment: could you help me out of this problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633957/set-annotations-title-as-current-address