# Setting the title and subtitle on a Map Annotation view

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I followed this question: [iOS - MKMapView place annotation by using address instead of lat / long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606031/ios-mkmapview-place-annotation-by-using-address-instead-of-lat-long) - to create a map annotation for a postal code as opposed to the long/lat values directly.

This works fine, however I would like to set the title and subtitle of the anno

```
CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] 
placemark.title = self.business.businessName;
placemark.subtitle = self.business.phoneNumber;
```

This is not working as the title and subtitle are readonly. How can I change the above so that I am able to set the title and subtitle?

Comment: Please refer the following for your query.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20645723/show-address-in-annotation-when-pin-is-dropped-on-map

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21541989/how-to-add-callout-into-individual-annotation-in-map-view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `MKPointAnnotation` instead.

**Sample Code :**

```
CLPlacemark *topresult = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
annotation.coordinate = topresult.location.coordinate;
annotation.title = self.business.businessName;
annotation.subtitle = self.business.phoneNumber;
[self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
```

Comment: You don't "have to" use MKPointAnnotation specifically -- just some class that implements MKAnnotation and has a settable title and subtitle (like MKPointAnnotation but you could make your own class).  Also, `locationManager.location.coordinate` should be `topResult.location.coordinate`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code. It may help you.

```
//set the title if we got any placemarks...
if (placemark.count > 0)
{
    CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemark objectAtIndex:0];
    annTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@ %@", topResult.country, topResult.locality, topResult.subLocality, topResult.thoroughfare];
}

//now create the annotation...
MapAnnotation *toAdd = [[MapAnnotation alloc]init];

toAdd.coordinate = touchMapCoordinate;
toAdd.title = @"Address";
toAdd.subtitle = @"Sub Address";

[self.map addAnnotation:toAdd];
```